# is there a way to have a iframe not reload the page?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, joomla

I have a page that opens in a modal on a joomla site. On that page, there is a hyperlink that links to a file on the server. That file opens up a joomla article. What normally happens when I have an a hyperlink on one article that links to another article is that only the content of the article displays in the modal, not the framework. But since I have the hyperlink forwarding to the file with the iframe, when it shows that article in the modal, it show the framework. Is there away to have the article show only the content, and not the framework while still having the iframe? I hope this question makes sense. You can see what i am talking about on this link, click on game template:

http://zaazoo.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=1&Itemid=2

if you go to this link, and click on round 1, and then hit continue, you would see how the articles display only the content and not the frame work.

http://zaazoo.thewebbusters.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=8&Itemid=4

any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show just the article you can add &tmpl=component to the URL you are trying to display.

Comment: Thank you for your response Brent. Do I just slap that at the end of the URL?

Comment: Actually, I slapped it at the end and it worked like a charmed. Thank you so muck Brent, you ROCK!!!

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the best solution but i would recommend using a PhP include like :

```
<?php include("your-post.html"); ?>
```

Since joomla is php based this should work, and unlike iframes includes will take the theme of the site or modal.

Hope this Helps :)